# How to change name string of file to format acceptable by fopen

Tags: c, string, filenames

I'm having trouble here with my filename. I'm just starting using program arguments and I'm already stuck with converting.
I'm writing a program that takes argument like this: `./sum filename`
and from `filename.txt` it takes data and does stuff. The problem I have is how can I change filename to `"filename.txt"` for `fopen` to accept it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *wrap_fname ( const char * );

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    FILE *filePtr = NULL;

    printf("\n%s\n", wrap_fname(argv[1]));
    getchar();
}

char *wrap_fname ( const char *name ){
    char *wrapped_name = NULL;
    int iterator;

    *wrapped_name = '"';
    for( iterator = 0 ; iterator < strlen(*name) ; iterator ++ ){
    wrapped_name[iterator+1] = name[iterator];
    }

    wrapped_name[strlen(wrapped_name)] = ".txt\"";

    return wrapped_name;
}
```

I already did something like this but I know this is just a desperate wrong try. Any help would be appreciated as I couldn't find any good function for that.

-- EDIT --
I finally got the function working, now my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void wrap_fname ( char * , char **);

/***************************************************************************/

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    FILE *filePtr = NULL;
    char *filename = malloc(sizeof(argv[1])+6*sizeof(char));

    wrap_fname(argv[1],&filename);

    if( (filePtr = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL ){
    perror("Error opening file...");
    exit(3);
    }
    printf("File %s succesfully opened",filename);

    getchar();
    free(filename);
    return 0;
}

/***************************************************************************/

void wrap_fname ( char *name , char **dest){
    char *wrapped_name = malloc(sizeof(name)+6*sizeof(char));

    strcat(wrapped_name,"\"");
    strcat(wrapped_name,name);
    strcat(wrapped_name,".txt\"");
    strcpy(*dest,wrapped_name);

    free(wrapped_name);
}
```

And now I got a bigger problem, which I have absolutely no clue how to deal with. After I run it with `./sum data` (after creating this file in my folder) it converts name properly to `"data.txt"` but `fopen` doesn't open it and i get a `perror` `no such file or directory`. Any way to make it work ?

Comment: [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) can help you. But before that you probably need to go back and revise basic memory allocation in C - `char *wrapped_name = NULL; *wrapped_name = '"';` is not going to end well (dereferencing NULL pointer).

Comment: `strlen(*name)` should be `strlen(name)`. Note too that you cannot `return wrapped_name;` unless it is either a `static` array, or has memory allocated dynamically.

Comment: Yesss, thank you Kaylum, it worked like a charm :) And yeah i know this code has many bugs, all corrected by now :)

Comment: `sizeof argv[1]` is wrong; that simply gives you the size of a pointer.

Comment: You have a fundamental misconception: `fopen` doesn't require quotes in the filename and there is no special "format" it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the wrapping function so now it doesn't add quotes and it works like a charm :) Thanks for the comment about `sizeof(argv[1])`, I didn't really thought that through. Anyway here is working code of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void wrap_fname ( char * , char ** );
FILE *open_file ( char * );

/***************************************************************************/

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    FILE *filePtr = NULL;
    char *filename = malloc(strlen(argv[1])*sizeof(char)+6*sizeof(char));

    wrap_fname(argv[1],&filename);

    filePtr = open_file(filename);
    printf("File %s succesfully opened",filename);

    getchar();
    fclose(filePtr);
    free(filename);
    return 0;
}

/***************************************************************************/

void wrap_fname ( char *name , char **dest){
    char *wrapped_name = malloc(strlen(name)*sizeof(char)+6*sizeof(char));

    strcat(wrapped_name,name);
    strcat(wrapped_name,".txt");
    strcpy(*dest,wrapped_name);

    free(wrapped_name);
}

/***************************************************************************/

FILE *open_file( char *path ){
    FILE *tmp_ptr = NULL;

    if( !access(path, F_OK ) ){
    if ( !(tmp_ptr = fopen (path, "r")))
    {
        perror ("Error opening file...");
        exit (1);
    } else return tmp_ptr;
    } else {
    perror("File doesnt exist...");
    exit(3);
    }
    return NULL;
}

/***************************************************************************/
```

Really thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: Just a point, you don't need to clutter the code with `sizeof(char)` because it is `1` by definition.